# Angular-translate localization - $translate.use not working on culture change and page reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, internationalization, culture

I'm implementing localization using:

```
Angular v1.4.2.
Angular Cookies v1.4.2.
Angular Translate v2.7.2
```

Localization is set up in my app.js file:

```
.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('nl-BE');
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('nl-BE');
    $translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader', {});
}
]);
```

I use a custom loader, because all translations are provided (and shared) by the Web API backend.

- apiService handles all `$http` calls.
- globalizationService handles all globalization related functionality. 
  It saves the currentCulture through a custom cookieService, which handles all `$cookies` calls.
- loggerService uniformly determines the best way to log information. Typically at least  to console.

  ```
  myApp.factory('customLoader', [
      'apiService',
      'globalizationService',
      'loggerService',
      function (
          apiService,
          globalizationService,
          loggerService) {
          return function (options) {
              var cultureInfo = globalizationService.GetCulture('currentCulture');
              var uri = 'api/globalization/' + cultureInfo;
              loggerService.Info('app customLoader', uri);
              return apiService.Get(uri);
          }
      }
  ]);
  ```

  In the controller of my SPA Template, I have the following function:

  ```
  $scope.ChangeLanguage = function (cultureInfo) {
      globalizationService.SetCulture(cultureInfo);
      $scope.currentCulture = cultureInfo;
      loggerService.Info('ChangeLanguage', cultureInfo);
      $translate.use(cultureInfo);
  }
  ```

This is triggered by two buttons:

- The NL button uses: `ng-click="ChangeLanguage('nl-BE')"`
- The FR button uses: `ng-click="ChangeLanguage('fr-BE')"`

---

Log results when running:

First load - Default nl-BE

```
INFO: APP CUSTOMLOADER: api/globalization/nl-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: fr-BE
INFO: APP CUSTOMLOADER: api/globalization/fr-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: nl-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: fr-BE
```

It's important to note that I close the session after having set the culture to one different than the default.

Second load - Default nl-BE, but Cookie set to fr-BE.  French translation is loaded as expected (i.e., my cookieService works)

```
INFO: APP CUSTOMLOADER: api/globalization/fr-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: nl-BE ** has no effect
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: fr-BE
INFO: APP CUSTOMLOADER: api/globalization/fr-BE ** sometimes this doesn't happen
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: nl-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: fr-BE
INFO: CHANGELANGUAGE: nl-BE
```

As you can see the following call does not happen on a reload:

```
INFO: APP CUSTOMLOADER: api/globalization/nl-BE
```

I would conclude that the customLoader is not refreshed.

As you can see in the logs, the proper culture is presented to `$translate.use(cultureInfo)`, but it does not seem to have any effect on reloads.

Any idea why `$translate.use(cultureInfo)` does not seem to work, despite being presented the correct culture?

Comment: My original hunch regarding my customLoader is correct, if I hardcode the JSON result everything works.

Comment: Same problem here :c